# jQuery determine number of div

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item second"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

I need to determine the number of div with the class `item` only after "`item second`" div? In this case, it will be 3.

```
var numItems = $('.item').length; //????
```

How would I go about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `$('div.item.second').nextAll('.item').length`

```js
console.log($('div.item.second').nextAll('.item').length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item second"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```